# dataframes list concatenation/merging introduces nan values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have these dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

a = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'A_val': [0.1, np.nan, 0.3, np.nan, 0.5], 'B_val': [1.233, np.nan, 1.4, np.nan, 1.9]})

b = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'A_val': [np.nan, 0.2, np.nan, 0.4, np.nan], 'B_val': [np.nan, 1.56, np.nan, 1.1, np.nan]})

c = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'C_val': [121, np.nan, 334, np.nan, 555], 'D_val': [10.233, np.nan, 10.4, np.nan, 10.9]})

d = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'C_val': [np.nan, 322, np.nan, 454, np.nan], 'D_val': [np.nan, 10.56, np.nan, 10.1, np.nan]})
```

I am dropping the nan values:

```
a.dropna(inplace=True)
b.dropna(inplace=True)
c.dropna(inplace=True)
d.dropna(inplace=True)
```

And then , I want to merge them and have this result:

```
id  gr_code    A_val    B_val    C_val   D_val
1    121        0.1     1.233    121.0   10.233
2    121        0.2     1.56     322     10.56
3    134        0.3     1.400    334.0   10.400
4    155        0.4     1.10     454.0   10.10
5    156        0.5     1.900    555.0   10.900
```

but whatever I try , it introduces nan values.

For example:

```
df = pd.concat([a, b, c, d], axis=1)
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
```

gives:

```
id       gr_code     A_val   B_val      C_val   D_val
1.0         121.0     0.1     1.233     121.0   10.233
3.0         134.0     0.3     1.400     334.0   10.400
5.0         156.0     0.5     1.900     555.0   10.900
NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
NaN         NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
```

If I try:

```
df_list = [a, b, c, d]
df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, 
                                         on=['id', 'gr_code'],
                                         how='outer'), df_list)
```

it gives:

```
id  gr_code   A_val_x   B_val_x     A_val_y     B_val_y     C_val_x     D_val_x     C_val_y     D_val_y
1    121      0.1       1.233       NaN         NaN         121.0       10.233      NaN         NaN
3    134      0.3       1.400       NaN         NaN         334.0       10.400      NaN         NaN
5    156      0.5       1.900       NaN         NaN         555.0       10.900      NaN         NaN
2    121      NaN       NaN         0.2         1.56        NaN         NaN         322.0       10.56
4    155      NaN       NaN         0.4         1.10        NaN         NaN         454.0       10.10
```

more dataframes:

```
e = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'E_val': [0.11, np.nan, 0.13, np.nan, 0.35], 'F_val': [11.233, np.nan, 11.4, np.nan, 11.9]})

f = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'gr_code': [121, 121, 134, 155, 156], 
                  'E_val': [np.nan, 3222, np.nan, 4541, np.nan], 'F_val': [np.nan, 110.56, np.nan, 101.1, np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` and merge the duplicated columns:

```
df = (pd.concat([d.set_index(['id', 'gr_code']) for d in df_list], axis=1)
        .groupby(level=0, axis=1).first().reset_index()
     )
```

output:

```
   id  gr_code  A_val  B_val  C_val   D_val
0   1      121    0.1  1.233  121.0  10.233
1   2      121    0.2  1.560  322.0  10.560
2   3      134    0.3  1.400  334.0  10.400
3   4      155    0.4  1.100  454.0  10.100
4   5      156    0.5  1.900  555.0  10.900
```

Comment: It works fine here! I am, trying, in my case, where I have many rows and more dataframes, and it gives me `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`. We have to put somehow something like this `df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]` ? or this `df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated]` ? But how can we add this? Because the concatenation needs to take place first, right? (upv)

Comment: do you have duplicated combinations of id/gr_code?

Comment: As far as I can see, no I don't

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example that triggers the error?

Comment: I will try to create bigger datfarmes and more of them? I am not sure

Comment: I can reproduce the error if I change id 2 to 1 in `a` (which would make it a duplicated combination)

Comment: Ok, so how can we deal with that? ( I am searching to find my case)

Comment: It depends on what output you would expect, for instance if you have one pair (1, 121) with value X and in the next dataframe twice the same pair with values Y and Z, what would you want to do?

Comment: I think we have duplicate indices? I f you see for example,`a` and `c` , they have `id=1` and `gr_code=121` . But the one, has columns `A_val` and `B_val` and the other `C_val` and `D_val`.

Comment: No , I don't have this situation. Every id is unique in every dataframe.